# When would you use XamlServices.Transform()?

Tags: .net, xaml

I'm looking over the MSDN documentation for the System.Xaml namespace and in particular the XamlServices class. I'm wondering what a use case for the [XamlServices.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd292671.aspx) method would be?

I've got nothing against it, I just don't see a case where this would be useful and I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transform takes a XamlReader and a XamlWriter.

There are two out-of-the-box writers and there are five out-of-the-box readers. Of course you can create your own.

So the Transform method allows you to stitch one of the readers and one of the writers together to transfer/translate/transform the xaml from one place to another.

There are a couple of scenarios when loose Xaml is useful but to me the most obvious two are:

1. Workflow definitions and
2. Design-time/run-time generators of UI

**EDIT**

This is the code from the Transform method:

```
public static void Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, bool closeWriter)
{
    if (xamlReader == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xamlReader");
    if (xamlWriter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xamlWriter");
    IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo = xamlReader as IXamlLineInfo;
    IXamlLineInfoConsumer lineInfoConsumer = xamlWriter as IXamlLineInfoConsumer;
    bool flag = false;
    if (xamlLineInfo != null && xamlLineInfo.HasLineInfo && (lineInfoConsumer != null && lineInfoConsumer.ShouldProvideLineInfo))
        flag = true;
    while (xamlReader.Read())
    {
        if (flag && xamlLineInfo.LineNumber != 0)
            lineInfoConsumer.SetLineInfo(xamlLineInfo.LineNumber,xamlLineInfo.LinePosition);
        xamlWriter.WriteNode(xamlReader);
    }

    if (!closeWriter)
        return;
    xamlWriter.Close();
}
```

Nothing fancy but just convenient so you do not have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comments after all this time! But since there's no separate transformation delegate, you'd have to write custom XamlReader/XamlWriter implementations that did whatever transformations you wanted. I don't recall ever running across anyone who's done that (other than the original XamlWriter performance replacement that Rob Relyea wrote years ago and it didn't "transform" anything). And if it's just feeding the XamlReader to the XamlWriter, how complicated could the method be? Why bother adding it to the framework?

Comment: I guess and hope they put some smart buffering in the method. I'll use dotpeek to find out but I expect nothing fancy

Comment: A added the source of the Transform method for reference